# SharePoint list forms not taking labels from Resource files

Tags: 2013, site-column, localization

I have a site with 2 languages i.e., English and Arabic. Here I have two different webs with their respective languages as default i.e., English for en-us and Arabic for ar-qa. I have created resource files for both languages.

I am creating site columns, content-types at site collection and using them in the list created under their respective webs i.e., en-us and ar-qa. Here the lists are created programmatically via visual studio solution.

While creating the list in ar-qa, the label texts for form fields in New, Edit and View forms are not being translated to Arabic. However when I check for the allitems.aspx page, it is taking the labels from the resource file as expected. Refer to the below screenshot and kindly help for the same.

**AllItems.aspx** Kindly note that here the texts are being taken from resource file as expected.

[image]

**List Form** - Here the texts remains in 
[image]